# Getting Undefined after subscribe successfully called in Service

Tags: angular, typescript

actually am new in angular and am trying to create an recipe app so here what i have created an recipes service in which there is two method i.e `storeRecipe()` , `fetchRecipe()`

`Recipe.Service.ts`
here is constructor in my Recipe Service

```
currentUser;
constructor(@Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private localstorage: StorageService, private http: HttpClient, private firstore: AngularFirestore, private authService : AuthService) { 
    this.authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(user => {
      this.currentUser = user.uid
      console.log(this.currentUser)
    })

  }
```

Now here am subscribing to observable and getting currently loggedIn User and save that user in `currentUser` when i console `currentUser` am getting what i want but in fetchRecipe method am not getting currentUser but in store Recipe method am getting currentUser how to get `currentUser` in `fetchRecipe` so then i get recipe when my component Initialize

**Store and fetch Recipe Method**

```
  storeRecipe(data) {

    let randomId = this.firstore.createId()
    console.log(randomId)
    return this.firstore.collection('Recipes').doc(this.currentUser).set({ fid: randomId, ...data }).then(i => {
      this.recipes.push({ fid: randomId, ...data })
    })
}
fetchRecipe() {

    console.log(this.currentUser) // <-- here am getting undefined
    return this.firstore.collection('Recipes').get().subscribe(data => {
      data.docs.map(i => {
        this.recipes.push(i.data())

        this.loading.emit(false)
      })
    })
 }
```

Comment: Hi, please can you include the code to the question, where you call the fetchRecipe? And I think you need to replace `this.currentUser = user.uid` with `this.currentUser = user` in  `Recipe.Service.ts` `constructor`

Comment: try `this.currentUser = user.body.result.uid` if you are using `httpresponse` as return type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the fetchRecipe() on component initialization, you could just pass the value to the fetchRecipe() once you get the data successfully as,

```
this.authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(user => {
      this.currentUser = user.uid
      console.log(this.currentUser);
      fetchRecipe(this.currentUser);
})
```

and access

```
fetchRecipe(currentUser : any) {
  use the value here
}
```

Comment: this is service and fetchRecipe method call in my header component

Comment: in store recipe am getting currentUser but in fetch Recipe am getting currentUser undefined i think you didn't understand my question

Comment: I got your question. theoretically, it should not happen unless the value is not set, try as the way I suggested.